# Locking the frame buffer device

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, framebuffer

I am developing an application for linux based embedded system which directly writes on the framebuffer device of the Linux kernel.The writing works perfectly. But the problem happens when some other event occurs with a demand of display(Like plugging a flash drive or a kernel message). Every time when it happens, the screen gets interrupted and the unwanted things appear on the screen erasing the previous graphics from the overlapped portion(other things remain unchanged).

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: "But the problem happens when some other event occurs with a demand of display(Like plugging a flash drive or a kernel message)"  What it means? can you elaborate? Demand of display in the sense?

Comment: Try Double-Buffering of your LCD

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Add `console=0` to the kernel command line. It disables both the kernel outputting anything to the console, and the console login. (For development purposes, I recommend having a separate boot option, so you can boot to a console.)

Alternatively, have your application create a new virtual terminal for the framebuffer, like X does. This avoids the kernel (kernel console, really) scribbling text all over your framebuffer.